# Preencher valor no combobox quando clicar em checkbox

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou fazendo um cadastro de clientes e nele tem um checkbox que preenche um input com "ISENTO, deixa ele como "READONLY" e precisava preencher uma combobox com um valor que está no options.
Porém já tentei de tudo e não estou conseguindo fazer isso, poderiam me dar uma luz?
Segue o código que fiz.

```js
function IEcli() {
  var cbocontribuinte = document.getElementById('tp_contribuinte');
  if ($('#iecli').prop("checked")) {
    $('#estadual').val("ISENTO");
    $('#estadual').attr("readOnly", true);
    cbocontribuinte.selectedIndex = 2;

  } else {
    $('#estadual').val("");
    $('#estadual').removeAttr("readOnly");
    cbocontribuinte.selectedIndex = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="col-xs-1 control-label" id="esterg">I. Estadual</label>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estadual" id="estadual" placeholder="" value="" />
</div>
<div class="checkbox col-xs-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="iecli" id="iecli" onclick="IEcli()"> Isento?</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Insc.Municipal</label>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="" value="" />
  </div>
  <label class="control-label col-xs-1"> Contribuinte </label>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="tp_contribuinte" id="tp_contribuinte" onchange="atualizaIEDest();">
      <option value="0">Selecione</option>
      <option value="1">1 - Contribuinte ICMS</option>
      <option value="2">2 - Contribuinte isento de inscrição no cadastro de contribuintes</option>
      <option value="9">9 - Não contribuinte, que pode ou não possuir inscrição no cadastro de contribuintes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Podes juntar código para reproduzirmos o exemplo? Assim podemos responder com código a funcionar.

Comment: Boa Tarde Sergio. Claro. Estou colocando o código

Comment: Sergio, só consegui colocar o trecho, pois o código é muito grande e não permite salvar a pergunta.

Comment: Acredito que o que falta é incluir o jquery na sua pagina

Comment: Boa Noite Pessoal.
Gostaria de agradecer a todos, todas as ajudas funcionaram perfeitamente, eu estava utilizando na página o bootstrap-select.min.js e ele estava influenciando no código, por isso não estava funcionando.
Uma pergunta: É possível marcar todas como resposta válida?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes fazer isso só com JavaScript e usando a propriedade do objeto diretamente.

```js
function IEcli() {
  var cbocontribuinte = document.getElementById('tp_contribuinte');
  var iecli = document.getElementById('iecli').checked;
  var estadual = document.getElementById('estadual');

  estadual.value = iecli ? "ISENTO" : "";
  estadual.readOnly = iecli;
  cbocontribuinte.selectedIndex = iecli ? 2 : 0;
}
```

```html
<label class="col-xs-1 control-label" id="esterg">I. Estadual</label>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estadual" id="estadual" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $cliente->getInscestRg() ?>" />
</div>
<div class="checkbox col-xs-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="iecli" id="iecli" onclick="IEcli()"> Isento?</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Insc.Municipal</label>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $cliente->getInscMunicipal() ?>" />
  </div>
  <label class="control-label col-xs-1"> Contribuinte </label>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="tp_contribuinte" id="tp_contribuinte" onchange="atualizaIEDest();">
      <option value="0">Selecione</option>
      <option value="1">1 - Contribuinte ICMS</option>
      <option value="2">2 - Contribuinte isento de inscrição no cadastro de contribuintes</option>
      <option value="9">9 - Não contribuinte, que pode ou não possuir inscrição no cadastro de contribuintes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` é JQuery. JavaScript puro `.value`.

Em JQuery:

```
function IEcli () {

    var cbocontribuinte = $( '#tp_contribuinte' );

    if ( $( '#iecli' ).prop( 'checked', true ) ) {
        $( '#estadual' ).val( 'ISENTO' );
        $( '#estadual' ).prop( 'readonly', true );
        cbocontribuinte.prop(n'selectedIndex', 2 );

    } else {
        $( '#estadual' ).val( '' );
        $( '#estadual' ).prop( 'readonly', false );
        cbocontribuinte.prop( 'selectedIndex', 0 );
    }

}
```

JavaScript puro:

```
function IEcli () {

    var cbocontribuinte = document.getElementById( 'tp_contribuinte' ),
        iecli = document.getElementById( 'iecli' ),
        estadual = document.getElementById( 'estadual' );

    if ( ieclie.checked === true ) {

        estadual.value = 'ISENTO';
        estadual.readOnly = true;
        cbocontribuinte.selectedIndex = '2';

    } else {

        estadual.value = '';
        estadual.readOnly = false;
        cbocontribuinte.selectedIndex = '0';

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Desta forma, o seu exemplo está funcionando perfeitamente.

Particularmente eu evito usar .attr() nesses casos.

OBS.: .val() além de inserir valores, também pode ser usado para selecionar opções.

```
function IEcli() {
    if ($('#iecli').prop("checked")) {
        $('#estadual').val("ISENTO");
        $('#estadual').prop("readonly", true);
        $('#tp_contribuinte').val("2");
    } else {
        $('#estadual').val("");
        $('#estadual').prop("readonly", false);
        $('#tp_contribuinte').val("0");
    }
}
```

Comment: **Particularmente eu evito usar .attr().** Por que?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

Comment: Por vezes tive problemas com alterações especificamente em formulários, values, readonly e checked, o melhor é usar .val() e .prop()

Comment: Boa Noite Pessoal.
Gostaria de agradecer a todos, todas as ajudas funcionaram perfeitamente, eu estava utilizando na página o bootstrap-select.min.js e ele estava influenciando no código, por isso não estava funcionando.
Uma pergunta: É possível marcar todas como resposta válida?

Answer (score 0):

Não existe erros no seu código! Simplesmente, como o  MarceloBoni disse no comentário `Acredito que o que falta é incluir o jquery na sua pagina` o qual deveria ter sido `Falta é incluir o jquery na sua pagina`. Para corroborar tal comentário faço executar aqui o seu codigo com o jquery.

```js
        function IEcli() {
  var cbocontribuinte = document.getElementById('tp_contribuinte');
  if ($('#iecli').prop("checked")) {
    $('#estadual').val("ISENTO");
    $('#estadual').attr("readOnly", true);
    cbocontribuinte.selectedIndex = 2;

  } else {
    $('#estadual').val("");
    $('#estadual').removeAttr("readOnly");
    cbocontribuinte.selectedIndex = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <label class="col-xs-1 control-label" id="esterg">I. Estadual</label>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estadual" id="estadual" placeholder="" value="" />
</div>
<div class="checkbox col-xs-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="iecli" id="iecli" onclick="IEcli()"> Isento?</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Insc.Municipal</label>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="" value="" />
  </div>
  <label class="control-label col-xs-1"> Contribuinte </label>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="tp_contribuinte" id="tp_contribuinte" onchange="atualizaIEDest();">
      <option value="0">Selecione</option>
      <option value="1">1 - Contribuinte ICMS</option>
      <option value="2">2 - Contribuinte isento de inscrição no cadastro de contribuintes</option>
      <option value="9">9 - Não contribuinte, que pode ou não possuir inscrição no cadastro de contribuintes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

> Se realmente queres usar JavaScript puro use a resposta do Sergio